# Can I use a light fixture box as a junction box for a Baseboard

Tags: light-fixture, junction-box

I would like to know if it's allowed to use an octagonal box currently used for a light as a junction box for two baseboard heater ( I need to relocate the current line).

The reason we need to relocate the first baseboard wire is because we are opening our roof to create an access to the future rooftop patio. The main wire was going down to a first thermostat in a wall we are removing and was continuing to a second one we want to keep. In other word, I need to pass this wire on the other side of the hole we are building and we are lacking some lengths unless we create a junction box somewhere. Since we have the light of our living nearby I wanted to use that box instead of creating one in the ceiling for nothing.

Our baseboard are on 220v circuits.

I am able to modify the depth of the octagonal box if needed.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 0):

The volume of the box probably will not be large enough to add the splices I would just purchase a 4 square box and cover. And a couple of clamps then attach the new box to a rafter put the clamps in run the wires in and clamp then make your splice in the box and cover. If you use a metal box the ground will need to be connected to the box. Using a new box you won't be overloading the light fixture box fill requirements.